# How do I detect that a hidden element gained focus and then pass the focus to a visible control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-validate

I am building a form with a [**tag input**](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager):

[image]

Specifically, I am using [**Tag Manager**](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager) however, this problem is present in other libraries.

These libraries work by  hiding the original `input` and rendering a custom control. They then updates the hidden `input`'s value so it will be sent with the form data.

My original mark-up looks like this:

```
<form id="submitForm">
  <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After calling the plugin:

```
$(".tm-input").tagsManager();
```

The DOM is updated to look like this:

```
<form id="submitForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden-tags">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Trouble is, I use the [**valiation plugin**](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) to validate form input:

```
$("#submitForm").validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    "hidden-tags": "required"
  }
});
```

When an input is invalid, it brings focus to the invalid element. In my case, the invalid input is hidden. What I want to do is, detect that the hidden element has been given focus and then in that handler, give focus to the visible control. How do I do this?

I do not think the `focus` function is invoked for hidden elements and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input type as text and display: none on the input element and you will be able to focus on the element using jquery validator.

```
<form id="submitForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input">
  <input type="text" name="hidden-tags" style="display:none">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: He's not having trouble getting the plugin to focus the hidden element... he's asking about how to transfer the plugin's focus to the *rendered* version of this input.

Answer (score 0):

> When an input is invalid, it [plugin] brings focus to the invalid element. In my case, the invalid input is hidden.

You are talking about [the plugin's `focusInvalid` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#focusinvalid) which is enabled by default.  The `focusInvalid` option will only accept a boolean `false` to disable this behavior, but it will not accept a function that over-rides this default behavior.

> What I want to do is, detect that the hidden element has been given focus and then in that handler, give focus to the visible control. How do I do this?

There is no option in this plugin that transfers or "passes" this focus from the actual element being validated (hidden) onto the element being rendered.